# Can 16A relay be used instead of 8A relay?

Tags: relay

I have a relay with 12V and 8A, it was not working properly. I want to change it with 12V 16A relay is that possible? Because I am thinking amper is the power of relay. If a relay can open 16A circut with 12V, It can easly open the 8A. Am I right?

This is relays Finder is broken,

[image]

Omron which is I want to use

[image]

Comment: Should be no issues. Coil drive current could be higher though. Do you have margin for that?

Comment: Do you have resistive, capacitive or inductive load? The maximum rated current via contacts in steady state can be higher than the maximum rated current that can be interrupted safely. Also the maximum rated currents may depend on what kind of load there is, and it may be limited by the power delivered to load too. So check the relay datasheets if it is rated at the current you want, the voltage you want, with the type of load you want.

Comment: You're showing an 8A DPDT relay and a 16A SPDT relay.  On that alone they are not compatible - one has one pole, the other has two.  If you need both poles, the 16A relay will not work.  Worse, the Omron SPDT relay is shorting pins 2/7, 3/6, and 4/5.  On your Finder relay these will be connected to separate poles. This could destroy whatever it is you're planning to plug it into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a relay can open 16A circut with 12V, It can easly open the 8A. Am I right?

It's not that simple.

@ocrdu has pointed out some important highlights - especially about driving the relay.

But there are two important things that should be considered:

- The load type the relay is switching (Motor, resistive, or capacitive)
- Inrush current rating of the contacts.

Please note that a big common problem that can be seen on relays is **contact sticking**, which is mostly caused by the arcs on especially switch-on events (Think of it something like welding).

[finder 40.52](https://www.finder-relais.net/en/finder-relays-series-40.pdf) is capable of switching a peak current of 15A. If the load draws a higher current even for a short time then the contacts may get sticked. So,

> I have a relay with 12V and 8A, it was not working properly.

That may be the problem that you are currently facing.

[Omron G2R-1E-12VDC](https://www.infinity-electronic.hk/datasheet/9d-G2R-1-H-T130-DC12.pdf) has a max switching current rating of 16A. So, even the nominal current rating is higher than finder's (16A<sub>nom</sub>/16A<sub>max</sub> against 8A<sub>nom</sub>/15A<sub>max</sub>), there's still a risk of encountering a contact sticking problem. So,

- Identify the load type
- Identify the peak switching current requirement
- Identify the max power

Comment: Tnks for awesome answer, Can I ask last question? Finder's switch pins are separete but Omron is unit. is that make any problem?

Comment: Omron's has two paralleled SPDT contacts. Finder's two separate SPDT contacts could be paralleled on the PCB. This probably won't make any difference.

Comment: @RohatKılıç No, that's wrong.  The Finder relay (40.52) is a DPDT relay.  The Omron is SPDT.  They are not compatible.  The Omron relay will short what should be separate poles.  This could easily damage the device it is intended to be connected to.

Comment: @J... Oh, yes you're right. I should have thought Finder one is the replacement for Omron's. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @mehmet There's a misunderstanding, sorry. You should check if the PCB has shorted tracks for Finder relay's contacts. If they are separate then don't even think about replacing it with Omron's.

Answer (score 2):

Both are switched with 12V, both are specced for 230V~, and the replacement can handle a higher current than the broken one, so no problem there.

You may want to look up the switching current for both; it could be the replacement's coil takes more current when switching.